# Obfuscation of WPF Project with ConfuserX

Tags: c#, wpf, obfuscation, confuserex

Obfuscated WPF Project by giving Post-build event Commands like this:

if "$(ConfigurationName)" == "Release" ($(ProjectDir)ConfuserEx\Confuser.CLI.exe $(ProjectDir)Confuser.crproj)

After Succesful build and Obfuscation Created Exe got crashing
 if I Obfuscate dll only then working fine but if I obfuscate Exe get crashing

```
Confuser.crproj
    <project outputDir="..\Release" baseDir="obj\Release" xmlns="http://confuser.codeplex.com">
       <module path="Sample.exe" >
        <rule pattern="true" preset="aggressive"  inherit="false">
          <protection id="anti ildasm" />
          <protection id="anti tamper" />
          <protection id="anti dump" />
        </rule>
      </module>
      <probePath>..\..\obj\Release</probePath>
      <probePath>..\..\bin\Release</probePath>
    </project>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because the xaml file name renaming is on. The exe has the startupUri setting with "Windows\MainWindow.xaml". But the MainWindow.xaml or whatever it is, is renamed to something else. Here is my project letting the renaming on except xaml file name. For me it works fine :

```html
<project outputDir="PathToTheOutputDirectory" baseDir="PathToYourExeFile" xmlns="http://confuser.codeplex.com">
  <module path="YourSoftware.exe">
    <rule pattern="true" preset="normal" inherit="false">
      <protection id="rename">
        <argument name="renXaml" value="false" />
      </protection>
    </rule>
  </module>
</project>
```